# Degree symbol showing weird characters

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that converts google map co-ordinates into decimal format.

```
function getDD2DMS(dms, type){

    var sign = 1, Abs=0;
    var days, minutes, secounds, direction;

    if(dms < 0)  { sign = -1; }
    Abs = Math.abs( Math.round(dms * 1000000.));
    //Math.round is used to eliminate the small error caused by rounding in the computer:
    //e.g. 0.2 is not the same as 0.20000000000284
    //Error checks
    if(type == "lat" && Abs > (90 * 1000000)){
        //alert(" Degrees Latitude must be in the range of -90. to 90. ");
        return false;
    } else if(type == "lon" && Abs > (180 * 1000000)){
        //alert(" Degrees Longitude must be in the range of -180 to 180. ");
        return false;
    }

    days = Math.floor(Abs / 1000000);
    minutes = Math.floor(((Abs/1000000) - days) * 60);
    secounds = ( Math.floor((( ((Abs/1000000) - days) * 60) - minutes) * 100000) *60/100000 ).toFixed();
    days = days * sign;
    if(type == 'lat') direction = days<0 ? 'S' : 'N';
    if(type == 'lon') direction = days<0 ? 'W' : 'E';
    //else return value     
    return (days * sign) + 'ยบ ' + minutes + "' " + secounds + "'' " + direction;
}
```

It was working perfectly fine for months and displayed the result like this:

[image]

And now all of a sudden, it displays a weird character (ยบ) instead of the degree symbol. I realise I have that symbol in my script but I have no idea what it does because the script is a library for mapping:

[image]

Comment: Can you not just remove the `ยบ` characters from your script?

Comment: For some reason the `ยบ` characters translates to a degree symbol so I need it.

Comment: `return (days * sign) + 'ยบ ' + minutes + "' " + secounds + "'' " + direction;` You have it in your code. Try to put a html entity: `&ordm;`

Comment: @Bruno then your question makes no sense. You say you want to use the degree symbol, but you also want to use those characters.... What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: person above beat to me to it :) -- http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/masculine-ordinal-indicator-ascii-code-167.html

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude That works! Thank you so much!

Comment: this one `&deg;`??

Comment: i think you can also copy the character and put it in the script directly due to been unicode

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The code outputted a degree symbol all this time with that code so I assumed the `ยบ` translated to a degree symbol. Now, it just shows the characters instead.

Comment: maybe you saved the script in some other format like ansi and couldn't translate the character

Comment: You are welcome. When you aren't sure of what charset you use (client and server) use html entities

Comment: Can someone please explain why/how it suddenly stopped working? Is it due to encoding or something like that?

Comment: It's because your charset. Sure. See if you are encoding in UTF-8 and say to client (browser) and server (generally apache) this is your charset (utf-8)

Comment: Aaaah I see. Thanks for explaining to me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&deg;` html entity should be used there:

```js
function getDD2DMS(dms, type){
    return 66 + '&deg;';
}

document.body.innerHTML = getDD2DMS();
```